# replace() method not working on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace

I have looked up this issue and most questions are for more complex replacements. However in my case I have a very simple dataframe as a test dummy.

The aim is to replace a string anywhere in the dataframe with an nan, however this does not seem to work (i.e. does not replace; no errors whatsoever). I've tried replacing with another string and it does not work either. E.g.

```
d = {'color' : pd.Series(['white', 'blue', 'orange']),
   'second_color': pd.Series(['white', 'black', 'blue']),
   'value' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.replace('white', np.nan)
```

The output is still:

```
      color second_color  value
  0   white        white      1
  1    blue        black      2
  2  orange         blue      3
```

---

<sub>This problem is often addressed using `inplace=True`, but there are caveats to that. Please also see [Understanding inplace=True in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457).</sub>

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to assign back

```
df = df.replace('white', np.nan)
```

or pass param `inplace=True`:

```
In [50]:
d = {'color' : pd.Series(['white', 'blue', 'orange']),
   'second_color': pd.Series(['white', 'black', 'blue']),
   'value' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.replace('white', np.nan, inplace=True)
df

Out[50]:
    color second_color  value
0     NaN          NaN    1.0
1    blue        black    2.0
2  orange         blue    3.0
```

Most pandas ops return a copy and most have param `inplace` which is usually defaulted to `False`

Comment: Note that there are real bugs that result in `replace` really not working in some cases (see issue [#29813](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29813)).

Comment: I just ran into an issue where `df.replace(x,y, inplace=True)` did *not* work but `df = df.replace(x,y)` *did* work. `x` was an `int64` and `y` was a `float64`

Comment: same with @MattR. inplace not working for some reason

Comment: Ah - I had similar issues where inplace=True had apparenty no effect, while assigning to a new variable showed that the replacement actually worked. I was using a regex to remove whitespaces & suchs.

Comment: I believe `df.foo(x, y, inplace=True)` is now deprecated, in favor of `df = df.foo(x, y)`

Answer (score 177):

Given that this is the top Google result when searching for "Pandas replace is not working" I'd like to also mention that:

> replace does full replacement searches, unless you turn on the regex
>   switch. Use regex=True, and it should perform partial replacements as
>   well.

This took me 30 minutes to find out, so hopefully I've saved the next person 30 minutes.

Comment: Exactly what I was bumping up against for a replace failing within a delimited string.

Comment: 5 damn years later and your answer is still accurate! This answer should receive a green tick mark.

Comment: OP here - I wrote this answer many years ago and have been living off it ever since - 90% of my StackOverflow score comes from this answer and one other (around how to time things in Python). Can't believe it's still a common issue for people after all these years!

Answer (score 19):

Neither one with `inplace=True` nor the other with `regex=True` don't work in my case.
So I found a solution with using [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) instead. It can be useful if you need to replace a substring.

```
In [4]: df['color'] = df.color.str.replace('e', 'E!')
In [5]: df  
Out[5]: 
     color second_color  value
0   whitE!        white    1.0
1    bluE!        black    2.0
2  orangE!         blue    3.0
```

or even with a slicing.

```
In [10]: df.loc[df.color=='blue', 'color'] = df.color.str.replace('e', 'E!')
In [11]: df  
Out[11]: 
    color second_color  value
0   white        white    1.0
1   bluE!        black    2.0
2  orange         blue    3.0
```

Answer (score 15):

You might need to check the data type of the column before using replace function directly. It could be the case that you are using replace function on Object data type, in this case, you need to apply replace function after converting it into a string.

```
Wrong:

df["column-name"] = df["column-name"].replace('abc', 'def')

Correct:

df["column-name"] = df["column-name"].str.replace('abc', 'def')
```

Answer (score 7):

When you use `df.replace()` it creates a new temporary object, but doesn't modify yours. You can use one of the two following lines to modify df:

```
df = df.replace('white', np.nan)
df.replace('white', np.nan, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was using this dict notation.

{old_value:new_value}

```
df.replace({10:100},inplace=True)
```

check the documentation for more info.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.10, pandas 1.4.2, inplace=True did not work for below example (column dtype int32), but reassigning it did.

```
df["col"].replace[[0, 130], [12555555, 12555555], inplace=True)  # NOT work
df["col"] = df["col"].replace[[0, 130], [12555555, 12555555])   # worked
```

... and in another situation involving nans in text columns, the column needed typing in a pre-step (not just .str, as above):

```
df["col"].replace[["man", "woman", np.nan], [1, 2, -1], inplace=True)  # NOT work
df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace[["man", "woman", np.nan], [1, 2, -1])     # NOT work

df["col"] = df["col"].astype(str)    # needed
df["col"] = df["col"].replace[["man", "woman", np.nan], [1, 2, -1])   # worked
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace({'white': np.nan}, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the case I've stumbled upon can help:

I've imported some data from a CSV file, via `pd.read_csv()`. The data are about the performance of a procedure and the cases that timed out are represented with 'INF'.

So, I thought I could clean these cases with something like:

```py
df = pd.read_csv ( "test-data.csv" )
df = df.replace ( 'INF', -1 )
```

However, 'INF' is intepreted as `np.inf`, ie, NumPy's infinite, and indeed,

```py
df [ 'col-with-inf' ] [ 'row-with-inf' ] == np.inf
```

is `True`. So, in a case like this, you can do:

```py
df = df.replace ( np.inf, -1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

One other reason, where i faced .replace function was not working and i found the reason and fixed.

If you have the string in the column as "word1 word2", when read from excel, the space in between "word1" and "word2" has the "nbsp" meaning non blank spacing. If we replace with normal  space, everything works fine. My column name is "Name"

```
    nonBreakSpace = u'\xa0'
    df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(nonBreakSpace,' ',regex=True)
    df['Name']=df["Name"].str.replace("replace with","replace to",regex=True)
```