# How to find the count of None values of multiple columns?

Tags: python

I am working on Jupyter, I have a large dataset which contains missing values. I have replaced the question mark to `NaN`, but when I am counting the missing values in the dataset, the command is not executing as it returns 0 value..
I have tried this command, but not succeed:

```
print(com.isnull().sum())
```

Replaced question mark by NaN:

[image]

Returning 0 value:

[image]

Comment: The problem is actually with `replace`. If you print your dataframe after it, you will see that it didn't work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593550/pandas-replacing-elements-not-working) for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), `replace` does not modify the dataframe in-place. Instead, it *returns* a dataframe with the modifications made.

Just change the relevant line of code to:

```
com.replace('?', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Glad to be of service!