# Unable to Replace Values In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I a dataframe with columns that have a combination of int and str value  in which I need to replace the value to 0. I have tried using replace to do this, but for some reason it will not work.

I could simply do this using the Find and Replace function in excel prior to importing the csv, but why do this when a funtion could simply perform the task without the added extra work. I have referred to the post below, but still nothing works.

[Pandas replacing elements not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593550/pandas-replacing-elements-not-working)

below is the code that I have used

```
crew_hours1 = pd.Series(crew_data.loc[:, 'Crew/Equip 1 Hours'])
crew_hours1.replace('<Not-Defined>', '0')
```

When I print the result the following output is returned:

```
0                  4
1                  4
2      <Not Defined>
3                  6
4                  2
       ...      
134    <Not Defined>
135    <Not Defined>
136    <Not Defined>
137    <Not Defined>
138    <Not Defined>
```

For some reason it will not work. I have used both inplace = True and regex = True, but still fails to work.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because of typo. User passes `<Not-Defined>`, data shows `<Not Defined>`

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is that the text shows `<Not defined>` and you are using `<Not-defined>` in your formula. This should work:

`crew_hours1 = crew.hours1.replace('<Not Defined>',0,regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

try `series.str.replace()`

```
crew_hours1 = crew_hours1.str.replace('<Not-Defined>', '0')
```