# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') after make_column_transformer and make_pipeline

Tags: python, random-forest, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding, multiclass-classification

First post on here, go easy on me with formatting.

Some of my data in a csv contains "?" instead of `None` or empty space:

54, ?, 180211, Some-college, 10, Married-civ-spouse, ?, Husband, Asian-Pac-Islander, Male, 0, 0, 60, South, >50K

```
    df = pd.read_csv("adult.data", names = ["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", 
    "education", "education-num", "marital", "occupation", "relationship", "race", 
    "sex", "capital-gain", "capital-loss", "hours/week", "native-ctry", "50k-income"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    test = pd.read_csv("adult.test", names = df.columns)
    test = pd.DataFrame(test)
    X_train = df.drop("50k-income", axis = 1)
    X_train = X_train.replace("?",np.nan)
    X_train = X_train.fillna("na")
    #replace all ? values in object dtype cols with empty space
    X_train["workclass"] = X_train["workclass"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["occupation"] = X_train["occupation"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["education"] = X_train["education"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["marital"] = X_train["marital"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["relationship"] = X_train["relationship"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["race"] = X_train["race"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["sex"] = X_train["sex"].str.replace("?", "na")
    X_train["native-ctry"] = X_train["native-ctry"].str.replace("?", "na")
    print(X_train.dtypes)

    Y_train = df[["50k-income"]]
    Y_train = pd.DataFrame(Y_train["50k-income"].str.replace("?", "na"))
    
    X_test = test.drop("50k-income", axis = 1)
    X_test = X_test.replace("?",np.nan)
    X_test = X_test.fillna("na")
    #replace all ? values in object dtype cols with empty space
    X_test["workclass"] = X_test["workclass"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["occupation"] = X_test["occupation"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["education"] = X_test["education"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["marital"] = X_test["marital"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["relationship"] = X_test["relationship"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["race"] = X_test["race"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["sex"] = X_test["sex"].str.replace("?", "")
    X_test["native-ctry"] = X_test["native-ctry"].str.replace("?", "")
    Y_test = test[["50k-income"]]
    Y_test = pd.DataFrame(Y_test["50k-income"].str.replace("50K.", "50K"))    #remove . proceding 50K in test file
    Y_test = Y_test["50k-income"].str.replace("?","")
    Y_test = pd.DataFrame(Y_test)


    
    features_to_encode = X_train.columns[X_train.dtypes==object].tolist()
    print(features_to_encode)
    income_map = {"<=50K":0, ">50K":1}
    Y_train["50k-income"] = Y_train["50k-income"].map(income_map)
    Y_test["50k-income"] = Y_test["50k-income"].map(income_map)

    col_trans = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), features_to_encode), remainder="passthrough")
    rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_leaf=50, oob_score=True, bootstrap=True, n_jobs=-1 ,random_state=50) #bootstrapping reduces variance, njobs = -1 uses all processor cores
    clf = make_pipeline(col_trans, rf_classifier)

    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Since there are mixed dtypes in my DataFrame, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66615924) for objects and regular `.replace()` for the other columns.  The ?s get replaced with empty space successfully.

I end up getting

```
File "/Users/vijay/Documents/CSCE 587/HW/Homework2/hw2.py", line 102, in <module>
    salary_random_forest()
  File "/Users/vijay/Documents/CSCE 587/HW/Homework2/hw2.py", line 95, in salary_random_forest
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 394, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 327, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 581, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 979, in check_X_y
    y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 989, in _check_y
    y = check_array(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 800, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 114, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

The dtypes for `X_train` are

```
age               int64
workclass        object
fnlwgt            int64
education        object
education-num     int64
marital          object
occupation       object
relationship     object
race             object
sex              object
capital-gain      int64
capital-loss      int64
hours/week        int64
native-ctry      object
```

and running `X_train.isnull().sum()` gives

```
age              0
workclass        0
fnlwgt           0
education        0
education-num    0
marital          0
occupation       0
relationship     0
race             0
sex              0
capital-gain     0
capital-loss     0
hours/week       0
native-ctry      0
```

I've been trying to figure this out for days and I'm getting nowhere.  [I've used this guide for RF classifier.](https://towardsdatascience.com/my-random-forest-classifier-cheat-sheet-in-python-fedb84f8cf4f)

Comment: Have you tried taking your transformer and classifier out of the pipeline and running them individually to see at which point the error occurs? Have you checked for np.inf values? Have you checked that all of the values are not too large?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mapping of Y for testing and training was giving `NaN` values.  I replaced the map with

```
 Y_train = pd.DataFrame(Y_train["50k-income"].str.replace("<=50K", "0"))
 Y_train = pd.DataFrame(Y_train["50k-income"].str.replace(">50K", "1"))
 Y_train = Y_train.astype(str).astype(int)
```